# Some of the Rows of CSV Dataset are getting shifted after translation. Please provide some solution for it

Tags: python, csv, translation

I have translated a dataset and after translation some of the rows are getting shifted to another cell, thus changing the contents of the cell.
(1) Dataset before translation
(2) Dataset after translation

| Brand | Model | Accel | Topspeed | Range | Efficiency | Rapid charge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volkswagen | ID.3 Pro S | 7.9 sec | 160km/hr | 440km | 175Wh/km | Rapid charge possible |
| Porshe | Taycan Turbo 5 | 2.8 sec | 260 km/h | 375 km | 223 Wh/km | Rapid charging possible |
| Volkswagen | e-up! | 11.9 sec | 130km/hr | 420km | 11Wh/km | Rapid charge possible |
| Volkswagen | ID.3 Pure | 10.0 sec | 160 km/h | 270 km | 167 Wh/km | Rapid charging possible |

Translated Dataset

| Brand | Model | Accel | Topspeed | Range | Efficiency | Rapid charge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Volkswagen | ID.3 Pro S | 7.9 sec | 160km/hr | 440km | 175Wh/km | Charge Rapide possible |
| Porshe | Taycan Turbo 5 | 2.8 sec | 260 km/h | 375 km | 223 Wh/km | Charge rapide possible |
| Volkswagen | e-up! | 11 | 9 sec | 130km/hr | 420km | 11Wh/km |
| Volkswagen | ID.3 Pure | 10.0 sec | 160 km/h | 270 km | 167 Wh/km | Rapid charging possible |

Here, you can see that after translation **11.9 sec** just got break into **11 and 9 sec** in the **3rd row**
Below is the code I am using for translation

```
from googletrans import Translator
myfile=open("ElectricCarData_Norm.csv")
f=myfile.readlines()

translator=Translator()  
with open("Electric.csv", 'w',encoding="utf-8") as op:      
  #for line in f:
    #print(line)
  translation = translator.translate(f, src='en',dest='fr')
  for trans in translation:

  #print(line," ",translation)
    op.write(trans.text)
    op.write('\n')
```

Please explain why it is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: Do you need to translate the hole dataset or just some columns?

Comment: Whole dataset, I have provided just few rows of it for sample.

Comment: You should open your raw CSV file in a plain text editor (like notepad, or even your python IDE) and see what's wrong: Your translator probably translates `11.9` as `11,9`, which is what moves everything one column over. Use the `csv` module to read and write your csv files instead of simply translating entire lines

Comment: But only the Rapid charge columns it's been modified right?

Comment: Maybe the character ! is causing the problem. Try to replace it by "", see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, you are right @PranavHosangadi , that it is converting '.' into ',' But I am not understanding why it is happening in only 2 rows out of 103 rows

Comment: @Zalak I don't know why it happens in only two rows (who knows how Google Translate thinks), but the way around it is to use the CSV module to read and write CSV files. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73394289/843953) below.

Comment: No, @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos cause it is happening in one more row where there is no ! mark.

Comment: Yes @PranavHosangadi, I got your code, but this code takes double the time of the code which I have used.

Comment: Well, I suppose that's just the price you pay for translating everything separately. Alternatively, you could try to quote all elements of the CSV before translating. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should open your raw CSV file in a plain text editor (like notepad, or even your python IDE) and see what's wrong: Your translator probably translates `11.9` as `11,9`, which is what moves everything one column over. I'm not sure why it didn't break the previous lines though

Use the `csv` module to read and write your csv files instead of simply translating entire lines. This will correctly escape any commas and you won't see the same issue.

For example:

```
import csv
from googletrans import Translator

translator=Translator()

with open("ElectricCarData_Norm.csv") as in_file, open("Electric.csv", 'w',encoding="utf-8") as out_file:
    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    for row in reader:
        translation = translator.translate(row, src='en',dest='fr')
        writer.writerow(t.text for t in translation)
```

which gives:

```
Marque,Modèle,Accél,Vitesse de pointe,Intervalle,Efficacité,Charge rapide
Volkswagen,ID.3 Pro S,"7,9 s",160km/h,440km,175Wh/km,Charge rapide possible
Porsche,Taycan Turbo 5,"2,8 s",260 km/h,375 kilomètres,223 Wh/km,Charge rapide possible
Volkswagen,e-up !,"11,9 s",130km/h,420km,11Wh/km,Charge rapide possible
Volkswagen,ID.3 pur,"10,0 s",160km/h,270 kilomètres,167 Wh/km,Charge rapide possible
```

---

Another possible solution is to rewrite your input CSV using the `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` option, so that every element is enclosed in quotes. Then, you can translate entire lines.

```
import csv
import io

with open("ElectricCarData_Norm.csv") as in_file, io.StringIO() as temp_file:

    reader = csv.reader(in_file)
    writer = csv.writer(temp_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)

    temp_file.seek(0)
    csv_temp = temp_file.read()

f = csv_temp.splitlines()

with open("Electric.csv", 'w',encoding="utf-8") as op:      
    translation = translator.translate(f, src='en',dest='fr')
    for trans in translation:
        op.write(trans.text)
        op.write('\n')
```

which writes an output csv that contains quotes around all elements:

```
"Marque","Modèle","Accél","Vitesse maximale","Autonomie","Efficacité","Charge rapide"
"Volkswagen","ID.3 Pro S","7.9 sec","160km/h","440km","175Wh/km","Charge rapide possible"
"Porsche","Taycan Turbo 5","2.8 sec","260 km/h","375 km","223 Wh/km","Recharge rapide possible"
"Volkswagen", "e-up !", "11,9 sec", "130 km/h", "420 km", "11 Wh/km", "Recharge rapide possible"
"Volkswagen","ID.3 Pure","10.0 sec","160 km/h","270 km","167 Wh/km","Charge rapide possible"
```

Note that the two translations are *not identical*, but that's a Google Translate quirk.

Answer (score 0):

If the translation doesn't keep the comas or the delimiter your dataset won't be the same.

It seems like not every column is going to change so I suggest doing:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_data.csv", delimiter= ",")
df["Rapid Charge"] = translator.translate(x["Rapid charge"].to_list(), src='en',dest='fr'))

df.to_csv(index=False)
```